# Call a function with the enter key in all browsers

Tags: javascript

I’ve been trying to make the enter key call a function for a specific text field. Getting it to work with IE is no problem.
Chrome and Firefox are another story, they trigger another function. The code on the text box is:

```
<input name="Phone" type="text" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13 || event.keyDown==13 || event.charCode==13){get2();preventDefault();}">
```

The code for the function called instead is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".button").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location=this.id+".php?"+$('form[name="reportform"]').serialize();
  });     
});
</script>
```

I tried modifying that function to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $(".button").on("click",function(e) {
    if (event.keyCode==13 || event.keyDown==13 || event.which==13){get2();e.preventDefault();
    }else{
    e.preventDefault();
    location=this.id+".php?"+$('form[name="reportform"]').serialize();}
  });     
});
</script>
```

I even tried swapping that function out for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#reportform').submit(function(e){
        get2();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
});
</script>
```

I found (keyCode, keyDown, charCode)==13 though numerous google searches and most of the functions on this site, but I have not been able to get it to work. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: do you want a solution in Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried similar approaches that you describe, for the task, but I have found a better way to deal with it. Simply use forms (and hide the submit button if desired).

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction();return false;">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" style="display:none">
</form>
```

[Enter] key will then cause the form to be submitted, i.e your function to be invoked.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/KKWL7/1/)